# Guava caching load method with an async service call

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, threadpool, guava

I have implemented a guava cache.In the load method of the guava cache I wanted to call a service asynchronously. I don't want to block this call for other thread, so, on it's call back I wanted to load the cache. How can I achieve this?

```
public CacheLoader(final DataValueProvider dataValueProvider) {
        this.parentExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new DefaultThreadFactory("cache-loader"));
        this.executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(parentExecutor);
        this.secretValueProvider = secretValueProvider;
    }
    /**
     * Call back method invoked by Guava to loads the initial value of the secretManager entry.
     */
    @Override
    public String load(CacheIndex cacheIndex) throws Exception {
       return dataValueProvider.constructDataMangerFromSource(cacheIndex);
    }
```

```
 protected String constructDataMangerFromSource(CacheIndex cacheIndex) {
       GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                .withSecretId(cacheIndex.secretArn);

        Future<GetSecretValueResult> future = awsSecretsManagerAsync.getSecretValueAsync(
                getSecretValueRequest, new AsyncHandler<GetSecretValueRequest, GetSecretValueResult>() {
                    @SneakyThrows
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        //I want to throw exception from here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(GetSecretValueRequest request, GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult) {
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
                        logger.info("Total time taken in the call " + totalTime);
                        //I want to return the value from here

                    }
                });
        try {
//This is currently blocking other thread

            GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = future.get();
            return getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("SecretManage call failed  " + ex.getCause() + " " + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://guava.dev/CacheBuilder ?  It recommends you switch to Caffeine, which has a specific async cache API as well.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can I achieve this with guava itself instead of caffeine? I looked at the cachebuilder method, but I couldn't find anything that can help the above situation

Comment: could you please give me an example with caffeine?